# Access single query output among all lambda function

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda

I have serverless applciation in nodejs using lambda function, I have stored all toast messages of my applications in one database table, and wants to fetch those toast messages in all lambda functions.
As lambda function works independently, I have to call database query fetch everytime whenever I need toast message in all lambda function but this approach looks time consuming to me and slower my application. Is there any way to access those toast message stored in table in a single query call instead of calling database query everytime any lambda function is called?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get those messages during the `init` phase of your Lambda. For your purposes, you can imagine the life cycle of your Lambda to have two phases:

1. `init`
2. "runtime" (that's what is called on every request)

What you need to do is to load those messages during the `init` phase, because this code is run just once, before the Lambda "goes live".

For NodeJS it could look this:

```
// This code will run only once, when the Lambda is initialized
const init = async () => {
    const messages = await loadMessages();

    // Perform any async calls here to fetch config data.
    // We'll just dummy up a fake promise as a simulation.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('fetching config data...');
        resolve({ "messages": messages });
    });
};

const initPromise = init();

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    // Code that runs on every request goes here...
    const config = await initPromise;
    console.log(config.messages)
};
```

Source: https://serverlessfirst.com/fff-function-initialisation/

In the `loadMessages()` you can query DynamoDB and get your messages.

Note: Your Lambda will "live" for a while (about 15 minutes). That means, that if you change your messages in your DynamoDB, it will take a while for them to be "live" as well.